# Why this subquery hiveql not work?

Tags: hive, hiveql

```
select (
    SELECT SUM(countNumber) from(
            SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp(AddTime),'yyyy-MM-dd') AS dateTime,
                   COUNT(productID) AS countNumber
              FROM product
             GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp(AddTime),'yyyy-MM-dd')
           ) as bb
     where aa.dateTime >= bb.dateTime
   ) as totalCount,
   aa.countNumber,
   aa.dateTimefrom (
    SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp(AddTime),'yyyy-MM-dd')AS dateTime,
           COUNT(productID) AS countNumber
      FROM product
     GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp(AddTime),'yyyy-MM-dd')
   ) aa order by dateTime desc limit 10000;
```

I wan't to query daily cumulative quantity.Why this HQL can't work?The Hive engine hint that:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 2:8 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'SUM' '(' in expression specification
```

Comment: I don't think you can add a subquery as a column in Hive, You should try adding that subquery in a JOIN and calling it.

Comment: You can't use where "aa.datetime" in the subquery where clause. It's not defined there

Answer (score 0):

Sub queries as columns aren't allowed in Hive. To get the cumulative quantity, use the window function `sum`.

```
SELECT dateTime,countNumber,SUM(countNumber) OVER(order by dateTime) as cumsum
FROM (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp(AddTime),'yyyy-MM-dd') AS dateTime,
      COUNT(productID) AS countNumber
      FROM product
      GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp(AddTime),'yyyy-MM-dd')
     ) t
```